# A3M auth for an already existing site

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, facebook-login, codeigniter-a3m

I am currently using tank auth in my project for authentication. Now I have decided to move into A3M as it also provides social integration. I am now stuck as no helper file is available for A3M integration to an existing site.

Please let me know if anyone is aware of the steps to be followed.

Comment: Are you looking for what files are needed to just plug a3m into an existing site? (I'm one of A3M's developers fyi)

Comment: yes actually. Any help would be great.

Comment: its quite easy actually, just look at what the 'default' codeigniter gives you and grab stuff from libraries / helpers / controllers / views / languages.  Only problem is pre-existing conflicts with what you currently have (ie same file names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just pulled A3M into a site I'm working on. It was pretty straight forward as @Jakub says. For anyone else who hits this page, here are the steps I went through:

1. Copy files from app/libraries; app/helpers; app/languages

   - Study files in app/controllers; and app/views, to see how to use the A3M system

     - The controllers can stay as is, you need to customize the views: sign_in, sign_up, sign_out, and account/*
2. Copy:

   ```
   app/config/account
   app/helpers/*
   app/libraries/*
   app/models/account/
   app/controllers/account/
   app/views/account/
   app/views/sign*.php
   (if using the A3M Views) app/language/* (ie language/english/account/ 
       and general_lang.php)
   ```
3. Configure app/config/account/* for your setup
4. Check the "Session Variables" in app/config/config.php
5. Add autoloads to app/config/autoload.php

   - $autoload['packages'] = array(APPPATH.'third_party');
   - $autoload['language'] = array('general');
   - // also suggest adding these if you check login status across your site:
   - $autoload['libraries'] = array('account/authentication', 'account/authorization');
   - $autoload['helper'] = array('language', 'url', 'account/ssl');
   - $autoload['model'] = array('account/account_model');
6. Add the following to the end of app/config/constants.php

   ```
   /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | A3M Extras
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   */
   /*
   * Define root resources folder name for js/css/img files
   */
   define('RES_DIR', 'resource');
   /*
   * Detect AJAX Request for MY_Session
   */
   define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
       strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
   /*
   * Portable PHP password hashing framework
   * http://www.openwall.com/phpass/
   */
   define('PHPASS_HASH_STRENGTH', 8);
   define('PHPASS_HASH_PORTABLE', FALSE);
   ```